# SSRS report - Group by on Date Part of a Datetime field

Tags: rdlc, reporting-services, rdl

I am working on a SSRS report that displays Date, Time and few other columns.

My SP returns just Date Column (which has time part in it) and a few other columns.

In the report I want to group by Date Part and show all details including the time (I used formatting option "T" to display only Time in Date column) in the details group.

For grouping on Date I used:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!TxDate.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Which seems working. However if I try to sort on other columns it is not working. Any thoughts/suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you edit the question and perhaps add some more details on the layout of your tablix? As far as I can tell there's not enough info in the question to answer it (yet). As a general note: don't forget that sorting on columns that are *inside* the date-group can be different from sorting on columns *outside* the date-group.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you were to add an extra column into your dataset that was based on your original date+time column but containing just the date. Then you can use this to do a simple group on that column.

For example, if the dataset is based on a SQL query and your date+time column is called `[Date]`, then add another column in the query as `CONVERT(DATE, [Date]) AS DateOnly` or something similar.

Comment: Yes...It does work when I sent Date and Time as separate columns from SQL Query...However I wanted to do Date+Time for performance reasons...Considering the fact that we are using RDLC, saving 8 bytes per row turned out to be a huge performance gain on a 100,000 row report....But now that my sorting is not working, I am almost going back to the way you recommended...Still researching to get a break through...Thanks